# How can i make one line to cover another in tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

`create_line(x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, fill=color)`

i draw white line
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRIeF.png)
then i draw green line (same as BG colour) with same coords
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6kN9.png)
and i got this: white line is stil visible behind the green one

How to draw line so it will make the previous invicible? (i must draw the line, clearing canvas is not an option)

i tried dfferent create_line parameters but it didn't help at all

Comment: Cannot reproduce if same function is used.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just delete the old line?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, and I see no reason why you would see the behavior you see. Tk will use the exact same algorithm for drawing each line, yielding the same pixels to be drawn. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://tkinter-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/canvas.html) you can add a `width=` in you call to make the line wider. This way it should cover the white line completely. Default value is `1`, so try out some values, maybe `2` will be enough already.

Use this for the green line only, otherwise both lines will be wider.

```
create_line(x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, fill=color, width=2)
```